# Cannot pass full array from controller in laravel to a view using redirect()

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am unable to solve passing of array issue

**below is my function in controller**

```
public function fetchData($id)
{ 
    $id=base64_decode(urldecode($id));
prod_detail=ProductDetail::select('prod_id','supplier_id','price','open_stock','discount_rate','min_order_level')->where('prod_id','=',$id)->get();
    return redirect()->route('prod_d_view', compact($prod_detail));
}
```

**below is my route**

```
Route::get('/product_view', function(){
    return view('/admin/product_d_mgt');
})->name('prod_d_view');
```

**below is my error**

> Undefined variable: prod_detail (View: \admin\product_d_mgt.blade.php)

I am unable to pass the full array from one controller using redirect()->route() to another view

Comment: `prod_detail=ProductDetail::select(...` is missing a `$`. `compact($prod_detail)` should be `compact('prod_detail')`. Your `return view(...)` in your route should pass `$prod_detail` to the view

Comment: It might be a typo when you posted it here, but in your controller, the line `prod_detail=...` should be `$prod_detail=...` (missing `$` before the variable name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use something like this:

In your controller function:

```
...
return Redirect::to('product_view')->with('prod_detail', $prod_detail);
```

And in your **product_view.blade.php** file (in resources/view directory):

```
@if(Session::has('prod_detail'))

     @foreach (Session::get('prod_detail')as $key => $value) 

     {{ $value->ColumnName }}
     {{ $value->ColumnName2 }}

     @endforeach

@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

It has typo. Missing **$** symbol before variable name **prod_detail**.

correct version:

```
public function fetchData($id)
{ 
    $id = base64_decode(urldecode($id));
$prod_detail=ProductDetail::select('prod_id','supplier_id','price','open_stock','discount_rate','min_order_level')->where('prod_id','=',$id)->get();
    return redirect()->route('prod_d_view', compact($prod_detail));
}
```

Comment: That's not the only issue. For example, the OP doesn't even pass the data to the view.

Comment: Exactly. That was simply the explanation of the error mentioned in the question.

Comment: This answer doesn't solve the error the OP get's though. The error is being thrown in the view, not the controller. Even with this solution, that error is still there since they never pass that data to the view.

Comment: i want to redirect() the url from controller and then along with it pass the full array to it